# Is it possible to ensure the diagonalization of the minimal coupling Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Specifically, we know that the Bogoliubov transformation ensures that a quadratic (bilinear) Hamiltonian of interacting bosons (or fermions) can be diagonalized.

Does the Bogoliubov transformation hold for the minimal coupling Hamiltonian of mixed fermions (charged particle) *and* bosons (electrodynamic field)?